# Can I make an emergency landing in Area 51?

Tags: emergency-procedures

In an emergency situation, it is permitted to land the aircraft anywhere. But does that include military bases such as Area 51? If my plane crashes and I determine that the safest place to land is Area 51, can I land there?

Comment: Just as a practical matter, when you're skirting the restricted area (which isn't just "Area 51"), there are lots of better landing sites outside, such as dry lakes, roads with generally very little traffic, and even a few actual airports.  To get to a decent landing place within the area, you generally have to fly over some rugged mountains.

Comment: @james What if there is a problem with the controls on the plane as it happened on United 232 and I end up inside the restricted area of ​​Area 51?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 You will meet with an unfortunate accident that the NTSB/FAA will be unable to corroborate the story of.